# how to use sed to tansfer virsh xml data to PCI BDF format

Tags: linux

I have two praised xml data as following 2 lines:

```
 <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x10' function='0x0 '/>
 <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x82' slot='0x10' function='0x1 '/>
```

I want to combine the value of domain,bus, slot and function of each line with ":" as below result:

1. $line1=0000:04:10:0
2. $line2=0000:82:10:1

above PCI BDF format (0000:00:00:0) is for next checking.
thanks,

finally, I added partial code into a intel example script for sr-iov host VFs management, it works for me.
the output result looks like below:
[image]

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DOMAINS=$(virsh list --all | grep "running" | awk '{print $2}')
vm_list="VM_Name   VF_BDF"
for DOMAIN in $DOMAINS; do
    temp=("$(virsh dumpxml $DOMAIN | grep -w hostdev -A9 |sed -n '/source>/,/<\/source>/p' |grep "<address" | sed "s/.*domain='0x\([^']\+\)'.*bus='0x\([^']\+\)'.*slot='0x\([^']\+\)'.*function='0x\([^']\+\)'.*/\1:\2:\3.\4/")")
    vm_list+="\\n${DOMAIN} ${temp}"
done
#echo -e $vm_list 

NIC_DIR="/sys/class/net"
for i in $( ls $NIC_DIR) ;
do
    if [ -d "${NIC_DIR}/$i/device" -a ! -L "${NIC_DIR}/$i/device/physfn" ]; then
        declare -a VF_PCI_BDF
        declare -a VF_INTERFACE
        k=0
        for j in $( ls "${NIC_DIR}/$i/device" ) ;
        do
            if [[ "$j" == "virtfn"* ]]; then
                VF_PCI=$( readlink "${NIC_DIR}/$i/device/$j" | cut -d '/' -f2 )
                VF_PCI_BDF[$k]=$VF_PCI
                #get the interface name for the VF at this PCI Address
                for iface in $( ls $NIC_DIR );
                do
                    link_dir=$( readlink ${NIC_DIR}/$iface )
                    if [[ "$link_dir" == *"$VF_PCI"* ]]; then
                        VF_INTERFACE[$k]=$iface
                    fi
                done
                ((k++))
            fi
        done
        NUM_VFs=${#VF_PCI_BDF[@]}
        if [[ $NUM_VFs -gt 0 ]]; then
            #get the PF Device Description
            PF_PCI=$( readlink "${NIC_DIR}/$i/device" | cut -d '/' -f4 )
            PF_VENDOR=$( lspci -vmmks $PF_PCI | grep ^Vendor | cut -f2)
            PF_NAME=$( lspci -vmmks $PF_PCI | grep ^Device | cut -f2).
            echo "Virtual Functions on $PF_VENDOR $PF_NAME ($i):"
            echo -e "PCI BDF\t\tInterface\tVM_Name"
            echo -e "=======\t\t=========\t==============="
            for (( l = 0; l < $NUM_VFs; l++ )) ;
            do
                guestVM=$(echo -e $vm_list | grep ${VF_PCI_BDF[$l]} | awk '{print $1}')
                    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                        echo "Fail to find the VF_BDF with guestVM. "
                        exit
                    fi  
                if [[ $guestVM == "" ]]; then 
                    echo -e "${VF_PCI_BDF[$l]}\t${VF_INTERFACE[$l]}\t\t${guestVM}"
                else     
                    echo -e "${VF_PCI_BDF[$l]}\t" used  "\t\t${guestVM}"
                fi
            done
            unset VF_PCI_BDF
            unset VF_INTERFACE
            echo " "
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: What is `$line1` here? Would you like the original line to be substituted in it before the `=` sign?

Comment: Did you already tried something? Please share!

Comment: @F.Hauri wait a moment, I'm know trying.

Comment: @neshkeev  $line1 just a example I want assign the result

Comment: @neshkeev the real case is I want to gather the VF assignment on Host for all running VMs under sr-iov , sorry I didn't explain clear.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
cat input | sed "s/.*domain='0x\([^']\+\)'.*bus='0x\([^']\+\)'.*slot='0x\([^']\+\)'.*function='0x\([^']\+\)'.*/\0=\1:\2:\3:\4/"
```

Where `input` is the file with the data

Comment: @neshkeev thanks, the sed command you share me works

Comment: **1.** Using sed to interpret xml files could work, but could become buggy if xml  structured change a little (order of attributs have not to be fixed). There are several tools and librairies for work with xml files. - **2.** For this this question don't match SO standard. So you'd better wait for this question to be edited (publishing code samples, specifying tool and/or language, etc...) or closed, before answering...

Comment: Pure bash sample using xml as input: `declare -A val;while IFS=$' </>\r\t\n' read -ra line;do [ "${line[1]}" = "address" ] && assign=("${line[@]:2}") && assign=("${assign[@]//=/]=}")&& printf -v assign "val[%s " "${assign[@]::${#assign[@]}-1}"&& . <(echo "$assign") && [ "${val[type]}" = "pci" ] && printf "%s;%s;%s;%s\n" "${val[domain]#0x}" "${val[bus]#0x}" "${val[slot]#0x}" "${val[function]#0x}";done <$file`

Comment: @neshkeev: actually, we are here to build a lasting repository of questions and answers, and *to that end* we do require questions to be complete enough for _others with the same problem_ to be able to figure out if the answers will help them too. These are not just F. Hauri's standards.

Comment: Next, please [do not assume who voted on your post, or why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686). Closing and voting are *normal curation features of this site*, and are not signs of toxicity. In fact, comments and posts using terms such as 'toxic' are a much greater source of issues than question and answer curation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , have you had a chance to look at the questions in the `SQL` tag? Most answers there cannot be helpful for others, because most of them are too specific. The OP could not edit their answer, because they didn't have enough points, but they were refused from getting help on this website, do you think they will stay with us? That is an example of toxic behavior to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , How come my comments were deleted, but the one with the a solution by @F. Hauri is still here? Will anyone ever find it? I know how to do it in pure `bash` too, my answer showed how to do it using `sed` since that is what was asked in the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , my answer was downvoted, even though it's helpful to the OP, if the one who downvoted it had objections, they might express it in the comment so I could fix them (or discuss), but the only objection there was is that I redirect the `STDOUT` to `STDIN` via `cat`, which is not a good cause for downvoting in this case. I believe the SO should forbid downvoting if no feedback is left, otherwise downvotes are not helpful

Comment: @neshkeev: regarding 'mandatory feedback', see [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436). We are not actually here to answer every possible question, that's not the goal of this site. Community curation is not perfect, so there will always be questions you can point to that don't fit the ideal, but that doesn't mean we won't try to strive. If you want to be open to feedback, make it easier to talk to you; being prickly and defensive about what can and can't be voted on won't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225054/discussion-between-neshkeev-and-martijn-pieters).